# Getting rid of the pop up saying, this page has an unspecified potential security risk, when using a network share

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, zones, security-zones

Basically, I would like to do .... this.....

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-the-annoying-this-page-has-an-unspecified-potential-security-risk-when-using-files-on-a-network-share/

.... via group policy. I have a *largish* number of machines to update, all at the same time, and 1 day to do it! Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Try the script here. http://serverfault.com/questions/63919/how-do-i-add-a-url-with-a-windows-group-policy-into-a-clients-local-intranet-zo

Answer (score 2):

You can add the zone in question to the Trusted Sites or Intranet zone in IE via Group Policy or you can set UNC paths to be automatically included in the Intranet zone. Which would you prefer? Also, does the path show up as being in the Internet zone?

EDIT

My preference would be to add the zones in question to the Trusted Sites zone as you may not want to automatically include all UNC paths in the Intranet zone.

Comment: This is the correct solution, but may not be optimal. Depending on what your users do, you may all sorts of sites in the trusted zone which end-users have set. Pushing a policy will overwrite their settings and block them from making changes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, adding sites to the various zones is an IE Preference and not a true GP setting, so the user is still able to modify the zones. This method is a quick and dirty method for putting the site into the proper zone en masse but doesn't stop the user from changing it once it's been "pushed".

Comment: I looked through the group policy options, and I believe I was given the option to import the settings but that means it would be the version of IE on servers, IE ESC? Or are these settings elsewhere in group policy?

Comment: It would import the settings from whatever version of IE is on the machine you're editing the GPO from. If that machine is running a different version of IE then the clients then you do need to be careful as the Security settings per zone have changed several times from one version of IE to the next. If the clients are running the same version of IE as the machine you're editing the GPO from then you shouldn't have any problems.